# ZMQ poll works in app and test under IntelliJ but fails under sbt/scalatest

Tags: scala, zeromq, scalatest

I'm using the org.zeromq java library for ZMQ and it works great in production deployment and when I run tests inside of IntelliJ, but if I try to run the same test via sbt from the command line on the same machine it fails with:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sun.jna.Structure.getFieldOrder()Ljava/util/List;
    at com.sun.jna.Structure.fieldOrder(Structure.java:868) ~[jna-4.0.0.jar:4.0.0 (b2)]
    ... (8 lines omitted)
    at org.zeromq.zmq_msg_t.<init>(zmq_msg_t.java:21) ~[zeromq-scala-binding_2.10-0.0.7.jar:0.0.7]
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.newZmqMessage(ZMQ.java:453) ~[zeromq-scala-binding_2.10-0.0.7.jar:0.0.7]
    at org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.send(ZMQ.java:368) ~[zeromq-scala-binding_2.10-0.0.7.jar:0.0.7]
```

where the test is simply this:

```
class ZeroMQSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with LazyLogging {

  "zeroMQ" should "be able to just send something" in {
    val context = ZMQ.context(1)
    val socket = context.socket(ZMQ.PAIR)
    socket.bind("inproc://zmqtest")
    logger.debug("start polling")
    try {
      socket.send(Array[Byte](1, 2), 0)
      logger.debug("done polling")
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => logger.error("ZMQ failed", e)
    }
  }
```

`send` is just an example. Same happens for `recv` or `poll`.

Since the same test passes when run under IntelliJ on the same machine and ZMQ also works in production code, it doesn't seem to be related to the native ZMQ installed, but rather how JVM binds to it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to further troubleshoot this.

**Update**

Prompted by @cdshines question, I looked at what JNA needs in the classpath to work and going by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858484/preparing-jna-for-use-in-eclipse), I need platform.jar and jna.jar. In IntelliJ they both from come my ivy cache:

```
file:/Users/arne/.ivy2/cache/net.java.dev.jna/jna/jars/jna-3.0.9.jar
file:/Users/arne/.ivy2/cache/net.java.dev.jna/jna/jars/jna-4.0.0.jar
file:/Users/arne/.ivy2/cache/net.java.dev.jna/platform/jars/platform-3.4.0.jar
```

which I figure SBT should resolve as well. Since it is not, is there a way to force SBT to do this?

**Update 2**

Added

```
"net.java.dev.jna" % "jna" % "4.0.0" % "test",
"net.java.dev.jna" % "jna-platform" % "4.0.0" % "test",
```

to my dependencies. No change in behavior

Comment: Can you post the classpath for both cases?

Comment: I'm using `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader` to get at the classpath, and under IntelliJ it prints out what I'd expect but under sbt it just prints `file:/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.5/libexec/sbt-launch.jar` which can't be right, since things do run. Is there a different way I should determine the classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `zeromq-scala-binding` depends on JNA version `3.0.9`, but you are running it with JNA version `4.0.0` which is not binary compatible.

You need to exclude JNA 4 from whichever other dependency pulls it in. You can use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to find out which one.

Normally I'd be scared about breaking the other dependency by forcing it to use JNA 3, but you say it works in production so you should be fine.

Comment: Using dependency-graph, I found out that the `jna` version above is not being used by anything (so I assume it's just IntelliJ. I manually included `jna 3.0.9` and did an sbt clean, compile and then run the test, but still getting the same error. Falling back to using `jeromq` for now.

Comment: IntelliJ should be out of the picture. You have the problem running SBT command line and there's `jna-4.0.0` right in the stack trace. Something must be pulling it in. I think sbt-dependency-graph has a flag to show more dependencies in its output, but I can't think of it.

Comment: Totally didn't even notice that the jar was in the stacktrace. Definitely strange because `what-depends-on net.java.dev.jna jna 4.0.0` reports no usage of 4.0.0 in sbt. Got some more digging to do.

Comment: Argh. It's a test only dependency which is only visible via `test:what-depends-on net.java.dev.jna jna 4.0.0`