# Discord RPC Module not found

Tags: java, discord, jna

https://github.com/MinnDevelopment/java-discord-rpc

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'discord-rpc': The specified module could not be found.
```

If anyone has this problem then your probably modifying minecraft.
Make sure to download the latest release of JNA. Get jna.jar and replace the old jna version.

Comment: It takes more than putting it on your eclipse classpath.  JNA needs to know where the library is.  Put it in your system PATH on Windows, LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux, and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on OSX, or in src/main/resources (assuming that's in your classpath), or use the JNA property jna.library.path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preparing JNA for use in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858484/preparing-jna-for-use-in-eclipse)